# Using #define value as a function parameter in C — why does it work?

Tags: c, file, fopen

In my last personal **C** project I've played a bit with files. One thing I've tried was having a `#define` value as a parameter. At the end is a code snippet so that you know what I mean.

My question is: Why is it working? Where is the data stored? Is it in line with ANSI C?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define FILE_NAME "test.txt"

void open_file(FILE**, char*);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   FILE* file;
   open_file(&file, FILE_NAME);
   return 0;
}

void open_file(FILE** file, char* filename)
{
   *(file)=fopen(filename, "r");
}
```

Why can I have the text as parameter instead of a char array, in which the filename is stored?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You defined a macro which gets substituted by the preprocessor so your call is actually `open_file(&file, "test.txt");` - did you not want that to work?

Comment: What is the expected behavior? What is the actual behavior?

Comment: everything is fine. i want it to work this way, but i want to know why i can have a string as parameter instead of an char array which contains the filename. also i want to know where the string is stored (stack maybe?). And last is this type of parameter in line with ANSI-C?

Comment: "why i can have a string as parameter instead of an char array" A string *is* a char array.

Comment: i know. i meant the text. sry

Comment: Who cares about ANSI-C, aka C89/90? You should learn modern standard C, which is C11 (or at least C99). And C does not have and never had a string type. You seem very confused about basic things in C. EIther you skipped chapter in your C book or you should get a better one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Preprocessor expands your code into `open_file(&file, "test.txt");`.

`"test.txt"` is a string literal. Compiler embeds it into the binary executable. It is loaded into memory when you load your program.

Let's analyze this simple example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        printf("hello, wolrd!\n");
        return 0;
}
```

We can generate assembly for that: `gcc -S hello.c`:

```
        .file   "hello.c"
        .section        .rodata
.LC0:
        .string "hello, wolrd!"
        .text
        .globl  main
        .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        pushq   %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        .cfi_offset 6, -16
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
        subq    $16, %rsp
        movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
        movq    %rsi, -16(%rbp)
        movl    $.LC0, %edi
        call    puts
        movl    $0, %eax
        leave
        .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
        .size   main, .-main
        .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609"
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

As you can see, the string was placed in the `.rodata` - read-only data section. You can obtain memory address of that string and try to access it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        const char *s1 = "hello, world!\n"; // both strings are identical
        char *s2 = "hello, world!\n";
        printf(s1);  // Read-only access - OK
        s2[0] = 'x'; // Write to .rodata - SEGFAULT (crash) here 
        return 0;    // we never reach here
}
```

Btw, pointers `s1` and `s2` should be identical. Compiler is able to optimize identical strings and store them only once.

Comment: thx, thats what i wanted to know. so its stored in the memory but i have no varaible-name to access it, except when i declare a pionter and initialize it whit this string.

Comment: Exactly. Now the funny thing is, that the string is read-only, but you can access it using pointer to non-const string, triggering the crash. This is shown using `s2` string. It's not a bug, it's a feature of C language. Some people joke that C is "high level assembly" - you can see why.

Comment: Link to [relevant reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal) for more information on string literals (just for completion)